# captcha image is not generating

Tags: php, codeigniter

I had uploaded my web app on different domain. I am having problem with captcha. It's not loading, instead it is showing a broken image icon. It was not even showing any error so I add `error_reporting` and `ini_set` function.

```
public function captcha() {
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        $string = substr(number_format(time() * rand(), 0, '', ''), 0, 5);
        $_SESSION["captcha_val"] = $string;
        $captcha = imagecreatefrompng(base_url('resources/images/captcha.png'));
        $black = imagecolorallocate($captcha, 28, 28, 28);
        imagestring($captcha, 5, 20, 10, $string, $black);
        $_SESSION['captcha_key'] = $string;
        //header("Content-type: image/png");
        //imagepng($captcha);

    }
```

now its showing following four errors:

> Message: imagecreatefrompng(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the
>   server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0
>
> Filename: web/inquiry.php
>
> Line Number: 21
>
> Message:
>   imagecreatefrompng(https://creativersity.in/eassist/resources/images/captcha.png):
>   failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found
>
> Filename: web/inquiry.php
>
> Line Number: 21
>
> Message: imagecolorallocate() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given
>
> Filename: web/inquiry.php
>
> Line Number: 22
>
> Message: imagestring() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given
>
> Filename: web/inquiry.php
>
> Line Number: 23

Please help me with this

Comment: "_https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0_" Obviously you're not allowed to load images/files from `https://` (or any) URLs. Could try to remove the `base_url()` from your image URL. Or enable `allow_url_fopen` if you can.

Comment: Link this:  $captcha ='resources/images/captcha.png'; ?? but not solving my problem can u guide me how I can enable allow_url_fopen

Comment: More like `$captcha = imagecreatefrompng('resources/images/captcha.png');`. Depending on your provider you might not be able to change `allow_url_fopen`. Set it in `php.ini` if you can. https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen